# Pytorch - How to add a self-attention to another architecture

Tags: python, pytorch, transformer-model

I'm a beginner with pytorch framework and I'm trying to add a multiheaded self attention on top of another architecture (BERT) (this is a simple question but I'm not familiar with PyTorch):

**UPDATE 1**

```
import math
class PositionalEncoding(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, dropout=0.1, max_len=5000):
        super(PositionalEncoding, self).__init__()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=dropout)
        self.d_model = d_model

        pe = torch.zeros(max_len, d_model)
        position = torch.arange(0, max_len, dtype=torch.float).unsqueeze(1)
        div_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0, d_model, 2).float() * (-math.log(10000.0) / d_model))
        pe[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(position * div_term)
        pe[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(position * div_term)
        pe = pe.unsqueeze(0).transpose(0, 1)
        self.register_buffer('pe', pe)

    def forward(self, x, seq_len = 768, mask = None):
        pos_emb = self.pe[:, :seq_len]
        x = x * mask[:, :, None].float()
        x = x + pos_emb
        return x
```

The problem in how to add the transformer is in the following class:

```
class CamemBERTQA(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self,bert_type, hidden_size, num_labels, num_inter_layers=1, heads = 12, do_lower_case = True):
       super(CamemBERTQA, self).__init__()
       self.do_lower_case = do_lower_case
       self.bert_type = bert_type
       self.hidden_size = hidden_size
       self.num_labels = num_labels       
       self.num_inter_layers = num_inter_layers
       self.camembert = CamembertModel.from_pretrained(self.bert_type)

       # ---------------- Transformer ------------------------------------------
       self.d_model = self.hidden_size # 768
       dropout = 0.1
       self.pos_emb = PositionalEncoding(d_model = self.d_model, dropout = dropout)
       self.transformer_inter = nn.ModuleList(
           [nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model = self.d_model, nhead = heads, dim_feedforward = 2048, dropout = dropout)
            for _ in range(num_inter_layers)])
       # ---------------- Transformer ------------------------------------------

       self.qa_outputs = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, self.num_labels)



   def forward(self, input_ids, mask=None):
       bert_output = self.camembert(input_ids = input_ids) # input_ids is a tensor

       # ---------------- Transformer ------------------------------------------
       seq_len = self.hidden_size
       x = self.pos_emb(x = bert_output, seq_len = seq_len, mask = None)

       for i in range(self.num_inter_layers):
           x = self.transformer_inter[i](i, x, x, 1 - mask)  # all_tokens * max_tokens * dim
       output = self.layer_norm(x)
       # ---------------- Transformer ------------------------------------------

       sequence_output = output[0]
       logits = self.qa_outputs(sequence_output)
       start_logits, end_logits = logits.split(1, dim=-1)
       start_logits = start_logits.squeeze(-1)
       end_logits = end_logits.squeeze(-1)
       outputs = (start_logits, end_logits,)
       return x
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you trying to add the Transformer network on top of BERT? You've used the terminology "self-attention" which itself is a part of Transformer network, but not the whole.

Comment: Yeah exactly that's what I'm trying to do, Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that you're trying to add a Transformer network on top of the BERT component. It has to be mentioned that the self-attention network is only **a** part of the Transformer network, meaning that Transformers have other components besides self-attention as well. I would recommend using the Transformer (which has the self-attention component included) as an encoder that receives BERT vectors and transforms them into another representation (in another space).

Try this instead of `self.attention = MultiHeadAttention()`:

```
self.transformer_inter = nn.ModuleList(
            [TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model, heads, d_ff, dropout)
             for _ in range(num_inter_layers)])
```

and then in `forward()`, call `self.transformer_inter` through a loop which will give you the representations produced by Transformer architecture. Like this:

```
def forward(self, bert_output, mask):

    batch_size, seq_len = bert_output.size(0), bert_output.size(1)

    # Transformer Encoder
    pos_emb = self.pos_emb.pe[:, :seq_len]
    x = bert_output * mask[:, :, None].float()
    x = x + pos_emb

    for i in range(self.num_inter_layers):
        x = self.transformer_inter[i](i, x, x, 1 - mask)  # all_tokens * max_tokens * dim
    x = self.layer_norm(x) # Transformer also normalizes the outputs from each layer.

    # x is the encoded vectors by Transformer encoder

    return x
```

Then using a `nn.Linear(.)` layer, do another transformation to map the `hidden_size` to the number of labels for your task, which will give you the logits for each label. These all should be done within `BERT` class that you have posted.

*Note* that the `TransformerEncoderLayer` is a placeholder class that I used above. So you have to either implement it or use open source packages. As Transformers are quite well-known, I think you won't have trouble finding an implementation of it.

Comment: What do you mean it's a placeholder?
https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.TransformerEncoderLayer.html

Comment: @Karl Thanks for the note. It seems that this class has been developed recently because I wasn't aware of that. I implemented this class myself in one of my previous projects, so good to know that PyTorch has the implementation of `TransformerEncoderLayer`!

Comment: Thank you @inverted_index you was very helpful ! But I still have some problems in the forward function: what do you mean with **pos_emb** and how can I get it ?

Comment: @JohnSmith Positional encoding is one of the concepts in Transformer architecture. It basically injects some information about the position of tokens within the input sequence. I recommend you to have a look at https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transformer_tutorial.html where all related classes have been defined. I think this link is basically what you need. Note all you need for your use-case in the encoder part. So you don't need the decoder part.